# What's a good way to implement a date filter in a list where the items have different timezones?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

We have an app that lists sport events. An event is associated to 2 teams (home team and away team). In the event list, we are showing the date of the event in the home team's timezone. We are storing dates in the database in UTC. We need to add a date filter in the event list page, but the problem is, since we are storing the date in our db in UTC and the dates in the event list is being shown in the home team's timezone, the date filter is showing unexpected results. the date is saved in our db as `2016-02-18 03:30:00+00` (UTC). When shown to the user in the event list it is `02/17/2016 7:30pm` because the home team is in Pennsylvania and the timezone is `America/New_York`.

now when the date filter is set to `02/17/2016` by the user, we are querying the the db to fetch all events where the date is `02/17/2016`. It will cause unexpected results since it will not match the event because in our db the date is `02/18/2016`.

One solution I can think of is show 2 date & time columns in the event list.

Date (UTC) | Time (UTC) | Date (Home team's timezone) | Time (Home team's timezone)

And inform the user that when using the date filter it will filter the events using date (utc)

But we're currently looking for a better solution. Any help / suggestion would be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT:

```
event 1:
    - date: 01/12/2016
    - time: 9:00am
    - home team's timezone: America/Chicago
event 2:
    - date: 01/12/2016
    - time: 9:00am
    - home team's timezone: America/Denver
event 3:
    - date: 01/12/2016
    - time: 9:00am
    - home team's timezone: Asia/Singapore
```

if the user selects 01/12/2016 in the date filter. It should still show the 3 events above.

Comment: Can you tell us what you are using for the date filter? Is this manual code you are doing or a framework? Some frameworks like in AngularJS, you can configure timezones into the filter.

Comment: I'm using a datepicker - https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker . And when the user chooses a date, an api request is being executed to fetch a list of events that is filtered by the chosen date. My question is about the UI/UX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new field in the database which stores the dates in its local time and use that field to filter the results.

so when you filter say, 2016-04-01, it will actually be filtering things across different timezones i.e. events that are not at the same Epoch time

so show me all events for e.g. Thursday, regardless of where the teams are (meaning that one team’s thursday is another team’s friday)

it will filter results that are localised to wherever the date was stored from.

Another solution is to use on the fly conversion query.

Example:

```
where convert_to_local_without_timezone(event_datetime, event_tz) = date_filter
```

It can be a user defined function - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/xfunc.html if there's no existing function that can achieve this.

Credits to:

Aries, Ryan Johnson and Nikki Erwin Ramirez